# TableLayoutPanel's Control Columns properties

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, tablelayoutpanel

I've noticed that every control added to the TableLayoutPanel is given "Column" and "Row" properties.
How can I get access to these properties through code?
thanks:)

Comment: Is this Windows Forms ? You'll get better answers if you include that in tags.

Comment: yes :) (a few more characters more so I can post this comment.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These properties only exist in the Properties Window, magic provided by the IExtenderProvider interface.  They don't exist at runtime.  Extended properties are:

- ColumnSpan.  Runtime: GetColumnSpan() and SetColumnSpan()
- RowSpan.  Runtime: GetRowSpan() and SetRowSpan()
- Row.  Runtime: GetRow() and SetRow()
- Cell.  Runtime: GetCellPosition() and SetCellPosition()
- Column.  Runtime: GetColumn() and SetColumn()

Obviously TLP was highly optimized to be used from the designer.  It's kinda of a pain at runtime.

Comment: This is incorrect (although that may be due to the fact the the answer is 3 years old)... For anyone that finds this now the correct answer is: 'tableLayoutPanel1.(Get/Set)ColumnSpan(ControlName)'

Comment: It is the first bullet :)

Comment: I see what you are saying. I skipped right over that because I though you were talking about running those on the control, not on the table.  Also, the part about saying it was a pain threw me off.  My-bad.

Answer (score 3):

Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763252/change-row-column-span-programatically-tablelayoutpanel).

This properties are added by means of "extending properties", something that other controls like `ToolTip` uses.

Answer (score 3):

Although the properties designer shows the row and column as properties of the added control thay are set programatically using a method on the table layout panel itself (SetColumn(control, index) and SetRow(control, index)).

This pattern of behaviour is similar the tool tip component and the error component.

Answer (score 0):

// Create TableLayoutPanel
TableLayoutPanel tlp = new TableLayoutPanel();

// Set the BorderStyle to Inset
tlp.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Inset;

```
// Grid has two columns
tlp.ColumnCount = 2;

// Grid has two rows
tlp.RowCount = 2;

// If grid is full add extra cells by adding column
tlp.GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddColumns;

// Padding (pixels)within each cell (left, top, right, bottom)
tlp.Padding = new Padding(1, 1, 4, 5);

// Add TableLayoutPanel to the Forms controls
this.Controls.Add(tlp);
```

[for more check this](http://en.csharp-online.net/TableLayoutPanel)

http://en.csharp-online.net/TableLayoutPanel