# set row/column span programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, label, tablelayout

I'm trying to make a dynamic layout to display data from a database, for that i'm using a tablelayoutpanel and I got it to where it puts the data in the fields I want it go to but I can't figure out how I would go about giving some of the fields a row or column span since some of them need to go over multiple fields

this is the code I use to create one of the labels that would need a columnspan

```
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Label()
{ Text = stat, Dock = DockStyle.Fill, BackColor = Color.Green, AutoSize = true }
, 7, row);
```

I did search on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763252/change-row-column-span-programatically-tablelayoutpanel) for a solution and I did find some that would set the columnspan, but they just wouldn't work with the way i create the labels.

```
tableLayoutPanel1.SetRowSpan([control name],[rowspan] );
//[] is what is supposed to be placed there
```

since this is the code I found and because I created the labels in the code I can't give the control name.
(It's very possible due to a mistake made by me)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: the question i have is not why isnt it working but how would i go about adding column span to the label if i create the label in code like the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code will work if you can add an **identifying** `Name` property:

```
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Label()
    { Name = "L1", Text = stat, Dock = DockStyle.Fill, 
      BackColor = Color.Green, AutoSize = true }, 7, row);
```

Now you can use that `Name`:

```
tableLayoutPanel1.SetRowSpan(tableLayoutPanel1.Controls["L1"], 2 );
```

To create the `Name` you could use the `Controls.Count` property:

```
string name = "L" + tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count.ToString("00");
```

Comment: i tried to set the name my self as wel but i gues i did something wrong with  the code since it wouldn't recognize the name of the control later on in the code. but i have something that works for now. but still thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 1):

Add methods are typically return `void`. If you want to operate with the item, then it make sense to either do it before calling `Add()` (construct complete object) or create an instance in the *normal way*

```
var item = new Label() { Text = stat, Dock = DockStyle.Fill, BackColor = Color.Green, AutoSize = true };
// do something with item here
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(item, 7, row);
// or do something with item here, e.g.:
tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumnSpan(item, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the ColumnSpan property of the label.

Comment: I know i need to set that property the question I have is how do i set the columnspan on that label.

Comment: As you have now worked out, you have to know what the ID of the label is.  So as per your example below, you have var label = new Label(), you can use label.ColumnSpan = 2, then add  the label to the panel controls.

Answer (score 0):

After some more searching i found a way to do it.
instead of trying to do it like this:

```
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Label() 
{ Text = naam, Dock = DockStyle.Fill, BackColor = Color.Green, AutoSize = true }
, 2, row);
```

im now creating the labels that need columnspan like this

```
var label = new Label();
label.Text = naam;
label.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
label.BackColor = Color.Red;
label.AutoSize = true;
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label);
tableLayoutPanel1.SetCellPosition(label, new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(2, row));
tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumnSpan(label, 2);
```